# I want to get my links to display inline

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my links to show inline.

I have tried changing the display among other things and have not been successful, can anyone please help me with this? I am having a hard time figure out how to get the 5 links to come up right next to each other in a row.

```css
.container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

.box-1 {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.fa {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 250px 250px;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-facebook {
    background: #3B5998;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.fa-twitter {
    background: #55ACEE;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.fa-youtube {
    background: #bb0000;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.fa-instagram {
    background: #125688;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.fa-snapchat-ghost {
    background: #fffc00;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Blogs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box-1">
            <ul class="fa">
                <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate any help that i can get on this. I was trying to use flexbox but that didnt seem to give me the output that i wanted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `display:inline-block` on the `<li>` element.  Also remove the `fa` class from the `<ul>` this class is reserved normally for the element that has the fontAwesome icon in it an you also have a set width to this in your custom css so it is giving your entire `<ul>` a fixed width.  Here is a snippet:

```css
.container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}

.fa {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 250px 250px;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-facebook {
    background: #3B5998;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.fa-twitter {
    background: #55ACEE;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.fa-youtube {
    background: #bb0000;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.fa-instagram {
    background: #125688;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.fa-snapchat-ghost {
    background: #fffc00;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Blogs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box-1">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set `display: inline` or `display: inline-flex` on the `li`, not the `ul`. The `ul` has `display: block`, but that's probably what you want.

I've added in `display: inline-flex`, as well as removed the `fa` class from your `ul`, as I'm fairly certain that's not what you were going for.

Here's a *minimal* example.

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.fa {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 250px 250px;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-facebook {
    background: #3B5998;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.fa-twitter {
    background: #55ACEE;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.fa-youtube {
    background: #bb0000;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.fa-instagram {
    background: #125688;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.fa-snapchat-ghost {
    background: #fffc00;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this change the fa class add new class name

```
.newClass{
  display:inline-block;
 }
```

And Give some margin to the li tags like

```
.newClass li {
 margin-left:2%;
```

}

Comment: Note that this will effect _every_ Font Awesome icon, which could cause very confusing errors later on.

Comment: @jhpratt u are correct i forgot that it a font awesome class.. I edited answer to add new class. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give `box-1` style `display: inline-block !important;` and  `fa` style `display: inline-flex !important;`

here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ozhpnk0x/2/) for the same
simple :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <style>
 ul
 {
 display:flex;  
 list-style:none;
}
</style>

<head>

 <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Blogs</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-       awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box-1">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-snapchat-ghost"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```